# Script in /etc/profile.d/ is not being run on X login (debian)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, x11, login

The following script:

```
name='ILITEK ILITEK-TP'
echo 'running touchscreens' | systemd-cat
ids=$(xinput --list |awk -Fid= "/$name/"'{print $2+0}')
echo 'after xinput' | systemd-cat
for id in $ids
do event=$(xinput list-props "$id" | awk -F'"' '/Device Node/{print $2}')
   path=$(udevadm info "$event" |
          awk -F/ '/DEVPATH=/{printf "%s \n",$7}')
   if [[ "$path" == *"1-5"* ]]; then
      screen='HDMI-2'
      #echo "$id $path $screen"
      xinput map-to-output $id $screen
   elif [[ "$path" == *"1-6"* ]]; then
      screen='HDMI-3'
      #echo "$id $path $screen"
      xinput map-to-output $id $screen
   fi
done
```

works perfectly fine if executed by a user. However, it is not run on login as an X session user, despite being in `/etc/profile.d/`, and ending in `.sh`. On the other hand, it is run if I log in by SSH, but that is the complete opposite of when I'd want it to run.

This must mean that perhaps `/etc/profile` isn't being called at all when an X session logs in? How would I be able to make it run? My window manager is Cinnamon.

UPDATE: I moved the script to `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` and now it runs, however it appears to be too early, as the `xinput map-to-output` does not work correctly yet, or is overwritten after script execution.

UPDATE 2: placing the script in ~/.bashrc works, however ONLY after starting up the Terminal. This is driving me nuts

Comment: Do you use a graphical login manager? Which one? They don't all read the `profile` scripts.

Comment: Hey, I will update to mark as solved. I use lightdm, and in order to get this work I had to create a .xsession file in the home directory of the user logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On debian systems, create a custom .xsession file and place it in the home directory of the user logging in, with your custom X commands followed by `exec {yourwindowmanager}`.

EDIT upon request, i.e.

```
xinput map-to-output 12 HDMI-1
exec gnome-session
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! Could you please show the actual file so others can repeat your solution?